# write a workflow, that extracts some fields from my list

Tags: attachments

I am attempting to write a workflow, that extracts some fields from my list and write those to an excel spreadsheet. Upon completion send an email to me with excel spreadsheet attached.

Comment: I don't have a great deal of experience in this, but I'll say this.  In SP Designer it is possible to create emails that imbed 'field:value'.  Therefore I imagine you might be able to do this.  One thing I would mention is that there is a useful tool in the List Settings, it is called 'Export to Excel' - it might be worth you exploring this in case it can be useful for you.  Perhaps using pivot tables in Excel could provide you with something useful too?

Answer (score 0):

In O365/SP Online, you can do this using Flow - the new no/low code building block way to create workflows, including exports and notifications.

You can create this workflow in SP Designer for SP 2016/2013/2010, etc. The SP 2007/2010/2013 workflow options are predefined and limited.

Process-wise, your list already has the information that you want, so you’d be creating redundant data with a new spreadsheet on each workflow launch, then need to manage all the separate spreadsheets.

Another option - since the list is your data source - create a view on your list that shows the desired fields, and set up an alert to notify you when new items are added, so you're not replicating content.

Good luck!